# Pointer - String C++

Tags: c++, pointers

**Works:**

```
char *s="sfdggh";
char *u="xcvbn";

s=u;
cout << s;
```

---

**Doesn't Work:**

```
char *s="sfdggh";
char *u="xcvbn";

*s=*u;
cout << s;
```

---

why? (I've searched, But Couldn't Understand)

```
//***************** EDIT **********************************
```

I got something. just confirm my understanding if I'm right.

```
char *s;
char *v;

char a,b;

s=&a;
v=&b;

s=v; //Address exchange
```

---

similar:

```
char *s="sfdggh";
char *u="xcvbn";

s=u; // Address Exchange too!/ Not Value Exchanging
```

Comment: Try enabling warnings on your compiler. You will see a warning assigning a string literal (of type `const char *`) to a `char *`.

Answer (score 4):

`s=u;` re-assigns the pointer `s`, which is perfectly valid.

`*s=*u;` attempts to overwrite the first character of the string literal `s` points to with the first character in `u`, which is illegal.

Modifying a string literal is undefined behavior.

```
char *s="sfdggh";
char *u="xcvbn";
```

are both string literals.

Comment: Can't Distinguish Between "re-assign" And "overwrite"

Comment: @ZobeyrFa well, those are inter-changeable. The problem is with what you attempt to re-assign (overwrite). Re-assigning a pointer is okay, re-assigning a string literal is not. For example, the problem is the same as `char* x = "bla"; x[1] = 'y';`.

Answer (score 1):

The const string literal can't been modified.

Answer (score 0):

`s` and `u` are `pointer`-types, which can be reassigned.

`*s` and `*u` are `char`-types which are stored in the **[code segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment)** of the memory.
Anything stored in the code segment is illegal to modify (otherwise the program could change itself, for example).

When you write string literals such as `"xcvbn"` in your source code, it's stored in the code segment of the memory as an array of `char`, with the rest of your program's code.

Comment: The fact that it's stored in the codes segment is an implementation detail. The problem is that modifying string literals (regardless of where they are stored in a particular implementation) is undefined behavior.

Comment: The fact that trying to access the code segment of the memory is what causes segfaults, is important to understand.

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing as *s=*u then you are changing the value stored char in first location of address pointed S by the char stored in first location of the address pointed by u.

Now

```
char *s="sfdggh";
char *u="xcvbn";
```

These two are string literal and act as constant.You can check the warning given by compiler you using g++ -Wall